# Podcast story about woman wanting to destroy machine distributing emotionally destructive ads

Tags: story-identification, dystopia, podcast

I remember listening to a story, probably on Escape Pod but possibly Lightspeed, about a near future in which ubiquitous machine-generated gendered advertisements, crueler than anything that could be designed by a human, destroying people's self confidence to make them receptive to advertisers' products. A woman decides to go after the machine distributing the ads.

> She succeeds at destroying the machine, but, without its voice, has no idea what to do next.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I received [an answer to this question on the Escape Artists Forum](http://forum.escapeartists.net/index.php?topic=12864.0): [Dead Merchandise](http://escapepod.org/2013/05/16/ep396-dead-merchandise/) by Ferrett Steinmetz (available free online in text and audio form). It indeed aired on Escape Pod.

Comment: *"Worshoppers."* Brilliant. Very Black Mirror.